# How to install and use Emojione Latex package in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, packages

I came across this wonderful package called Emojione here - [Emojione](https://github.com/benjamin-weiss/emojione-latex). Can someone tell me how to install and use this package in beamer.[placing the .sty file along with the whole package in the local texmf and updating FDNB doesn't seem to be enough]

Here's the MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\author{Karthik}
\title{My title}
\usetheme{default}

\usepackage{emojione}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
    \begin{frame}[t]\frametitle{First frame}
        I am trying to insert an emoji here  \emojialien
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

There is no pdf output. The error messages I'm getting are

```
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:57: Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \bool_if:nTF. [\bool_if:nTF { \xetex_if_engine_p:]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:57: Undefined control sequence. [\bool_if:nTF { \xetex_if_engine_p:]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:57: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! [\bool_if:nTF { \xetex_if_engine_p:]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:57: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. [\bool_if:nTF { \xetex_if_engine_p: |]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:57: Undefined control sequence. [...xetex_if_engine_p: || \luatex_if_engine_p:]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:57: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! [...xetex_if_engine_p: || \luatex_if_engine_p:]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:57: Too many }'s. [...etex_if_engine_p: || \luatex_if_engine_p:}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:67: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! [  \cs_new:Npn \emojione_define:nnnn]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:73: Undefined control sequence. [...ine:nnnn{}{onezerozero}{128175}{1f4af}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:73: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. [...ine:nnnn{}{onezerozero}{128175}{1f4af}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:73: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/1f4af.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...ine:nnnn{}{onezerozero}{128175}{1f4af}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:74: Undefined control sequence. [...nnnn{}{onetwothreefour}{128290}{1f522}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:74: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/1f522.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...nnnn{}{onetwothreefour}{128290}{1f522}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:75: Undefined control sequence. [...efine:nnnn{}{eightball}{127921}{1f3b1}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:75: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/1f3b1.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...efine:nnnn{}{eightball}{127921}{1f3b1}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:76: Undefined control sequence. [\emojione_define:nnnn{}{a}{127344}{1f170}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:76: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/1f170.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [\emojione_define:nnnn{}{a}{127344}{1f170}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:77: Undefined control sequence. [...jione_define:nnnn{}{ab}{127374}{1f18e}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:77: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/1f18e.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...jione_define:nnnn{}{ab}{127374}{1f18e}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:78: Undefined control sequence. [...ione_define:nnnn{}{abc}{128292}{1f524}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:78: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/1f524.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...ione_define:nnnn{}{abc}{128292}{1f524}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:79: Undefined control sequence. [...one_define:nnnn{}{abcd}{128289}{1f521}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:79: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/1f521.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...one_define:nnnn{}{abcd}{128289}{1f521}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:80: Undefined control sequence. [...e_define:nnnn{}{accept}{127569}{1f251}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:80: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/1f251.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...e_define:nnnn{}{accept}{127569}{1f251}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:81: Undefined control sequence. [...e:nnnn{}{aerialtramway}{128673}{1f6a1}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:81: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/1f6a1.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...e:nnnn{}{aerialtramway}{128673}{1f6a1}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:82: Undefined control sequence. [...one_define:nnnn{✈}{airplane}{9992}{2708}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:82: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/2708.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...one_define:nnnn{✈}{airplane}{9992}{2708}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:83: Undefined control sequence. [...nnn{}{airplanearriving}{128748}{1f6ec}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:83: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/1f6ec.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...nnn{}{airplanearriving}{128748}{1f6ec}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:84: Undefined control sequence. [...nn{}{airplanedeparture}{128747}{1f6eb}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:84: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/1f6eb.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...nn{}{airplanedeparture}{128747}{1f6eb}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:85: Undefined control sequence. [...e:nnnn{}{airplanesmall}{128745}{1f6e9}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:85: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/1f6e9.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...e:nnnn{}{airplanesmall}{128745}{1f6e9}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:86: Undefined control sequence. [...e_define:nnnn{⏰}{alarmclock}{9200}{23f0}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:86: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/23f0.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...e_define:nnnn{⏰}{alarmclock}{9200}{23f0}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:87: Undefined control sequence. [...ione_define:nnnn{⚗}{alembic}{9879}{2697}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:87: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/2697.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...ione_define:nnnn{⚗}{alembic}{9879}{2697}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:88: Undefined control sequence. [...ne_define:nnnn{}{alien}{128125}{1f47d}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:88: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/1f47d.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...ne_define:nnnn{}{alien}{128125}{1f47d}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:89: Undefined control sequence. [...efine:nnnn{}{ambulance}{128657}{1f691}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:89: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/1f691.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...efine:nnnn{}{ambulance}{128657}{1f691}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:90: Undefined control sequence. [..._define:nnnn{}{amphora}{127994}{1f3fa}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:90: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/1f3fa.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [..._define:nnnn{}{amphora}{127994}{1f3fa}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:91: Undefined control sequence. [...jione_define:nnnn{⚓}{anchor}{9875}{2693}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:91: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/2693.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...jione_define:nnnn{⚓}{anchor}{9875}{2693}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:92: Undefined control sequence. [...ne_define:nnnn{}{angel}{128124}{1f47c}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:92: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/1f47c.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...ne_define:nnnn{}{angel}{128124}{1f47c}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:93: Undefined control sequence. [...n{}{angeltoneone}{127995}{1f47c-1f3fb}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:93: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/1f47c-1f3fb.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...n{}{angeltoneone}{127995}{1f47c-1f3fb}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:94: Undefined control sequence. [...n{}{angeltonetwo}{127996}{1f47c-1f3fc}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:94: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/1f47c-1f3fc.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...n{}{angeltonetwo}{127996}{1f47c-1f3fc}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:95: Undefined control sequence. [...}{angeltonethree}{127997}{1f47c-1f3fd}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:95: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/1f47c-1f3fd.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...}{angeltonethree}{127997}{1f47c-1f3fd}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:96: Undefined control sequence. [...{}{angeltonefour}{127998}{1f47c-1f3fe}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:96: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/1f47c-1f3fe.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...{}{angeltonefour}{127998}{1f47c-1f3fe}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:97: Undefined control sequence. [...{}{angeltonefive}{127999}{1f47c-1f3ff}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:97: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/1f47c-1f3ff.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...{}{angeltonefive}{127999}{1f47c-1f3ff}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:98: Undefined control sequence. [...ne_define:nnnn{}{anger}{128162}{1f4a2}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:98: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/1f4a2.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...ne_define:nnnn{}{anger}{128162}{1f4a2}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:99: Undefined control sequence. [...fine:nnnn{}{angerright}{128495}{1f5ef}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:99: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/1f5ef.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...fine:nnnn{}{angerright}{128495}{1f5ef}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:100: Undefined control sequence. [...e_define:nnnn{}{angry}{128544}{1f620}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:100: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/1f620.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...e_define:nnnn{}{angry}{128544}{1f620}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:101: Undefined control sequence. [...fine:nnnn{}{anguished}{128551}{1f627}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:101: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/1f627.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...fine:nnnn{}{anguished}{128551}{1f627}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:102: Undefined control sequence. [...one_define:nnnn{}{ant}{128028}{1f41c}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:102: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/1f41c.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...one_define:nnnn{}{ant}{128028}{1f41c}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:103: Undefined control sequence. [...e_define:nnnn{}{apple}{127822}{1f34e}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:103: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/1f34e.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...e_define:nnnn{}{apple}{127822}{1f34e}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:104: Undefined control sequence. [...ne_define:nnnn{♒}{aquarius}{9810}{2652}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:104: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/2652.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...ne_define:nnnn{♒}{aquarius}{9810}{2652}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:105: Undefined control sequence. [...jione_define:nnnn{♈}{aries}{9800}{2648}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:105: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/2648.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...jione_define:nnnn{♈}{aries}{9800}{2648}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:106: Undefined control sequence. [...fine:nnnn{◀}{arrowbackward}{9664}{25c0}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:106: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/25c0.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...fine:nnnn{◀}{arrowbackward}{9664}{25c0}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:107: Undefined control sequence. [...ne:nnnn{⏬}{arrowdoubledown}{9196}{23ec}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:107: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/23ec.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...ne:nnnn{⏬}{arrowdoubledown}{9196}{23ec}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:108: Undefined control sequence. [...fine:nnnn{⏫}{arrowdoubleup}{9195}{23eb}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:108: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/23eb.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...fine:nnnn{⏫}{arrowdoubleup}{9195}{23eb}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:109: Undefined control sequence. [..._define:nnnn{⬇}{arrowdown}{11015}{2b07}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:109: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/2b07.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [..._define:nnnn{⬇}{arrowdown}{11015}{2b07}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:110: Undefined control sequence. [...nnnn{}{arrowdownsmall}{128317}{1f53d}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:110: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/1f53d.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...nnnn{}{arrowdownsmall}{128317}{1f53d}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:111: Undefined control sequence. [...efine:nnnn{▶}{arrowforward}{9654}{25b6}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:111: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/25b6.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...efine:nnnn{▶}{arrowforward}{9654}{25b6}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:112: Undefined control sequence. [...:nnnn{⤵}{arrowheadingdown}{10549}{2935}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:112: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/2935.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...:nnnn{⤵}{arrowheadingdown}{10549}{2935}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:113: Undefined control sequence. [...ne:nnnn{⤴}{arrowheadingup}{10548}{2934}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:113: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/2934.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...ne:nnnn{⤴}{arrowheadingup}{10548}{2934}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:114: Undefined control sequence. [..._define:nnnn{⬅}{arrowleft}{11013}{2b05}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:114: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/2b05.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [..._define:nnnn{⬅}{arrowleft}{11013}{2b05}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:115: Undefined control sequence. [...ine:nnnn{↙}{arrowlowerleft}{8601}{2199}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:115: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/2199.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...ine:nnnn{↙}{arrowlowerleft}{8601}{2199}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:116: Undefined control sequence. [...ne:nnnn{↘}{arrowlowerright}{8600}{2198}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:116: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/2198.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...ne:nnnn{↘}{arrowlowerright}{8600}{2198}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:117: Undefined control sequence. [...define:nnnn{➡}{arrowright}{10145}{27a1}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:117: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/27a1.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...define:nnnn{➡}{arrowright}{10145}{27a1}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:118: Undefined control sequence. [...ine:nnnn{↪}{arrowrighthook}{8618}{21aa}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:118: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/21aa.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...ine:nnnn{↪}{arrowrighthook}{8618}{21aa}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:119: Undefined control sequence. [...ne_define:nnnn{⬆}{arrowup}{11014}{2b06}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:119: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/2b06.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...ne_define:nnnn{⬆}{arrowup}{11014}{2b06}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:120: Undefined control sequence. [...define:nnnn{↕}{arrowupdown}{8597}{2195}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:120: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/2195.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...define:nnnn{↕}{arrowupdown}{8597}{2195}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:121: Undefined control sequence. [...e:nnnn{}{arrowupsmall}{128316}{1f53c}]
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:121: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./pdf/1f53c.pdf' not found: using draft setting. [...e:nnnn{}{arrowupsmall}{128316}{1f53c}]
Too many errors. TeX stopped.

Warnings:

H:\Miktex\tex\latex\newunicodechar\newunicodechar.sty: Package newunicodechar Warning: This package won't work without loading(newunicodechar)                `inputenc' or `inputenx' with the `utf8' option.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:73: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/1f4af.pdf' not found on input line 73.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:74: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/1f522.pdf' not found on input line 74.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:75: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/1f3b1.pdf' not found on input line 75.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:76: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/1f170.pdf' not found on input line 76.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:77: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/1f18e.pdf' not found on input line 77.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:78: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/1f524.pdf' not found on input line 78.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:79: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/1f521.pdf' not found on input line 79.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:80: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/1f251.pdf' not found on input line 80.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:81: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/1f6a1.pdf' not found on input line 81.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:82: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/2708.pdf' not found on input line 82.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:83: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/1f6ec.pdf' not found on input line 83.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:84: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/1f6eb.pdf' not found on input line 84.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:85: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/1f6e9.pdf' not found on input line 85.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:86: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/23f0.pdf' not found on input line 86.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:87: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/2697.pdf' not found on input line 87.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:88: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/1f47d.pdf' not found on input line 88.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:89: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/1f691.pdf' not found on input line 89.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:90: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/1f3fa.pdf' not found on input line 90.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:91: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/2693.pdf' not found on input line 91.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:92: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/1f47c.pdf' not found on input line 92.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:93: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/1f47c-1f3fb.pdf' not found on input line 93.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:94: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/1f47c-1f3fc.pdf' not found on input line 94.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:95: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/1f47c-1f3fd.pdf' not found on input line 95.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:96: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/1f47c-1f3fe.pdf' not found on input line 96.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:97: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/1f47c-1f3ff.pdf' not found on input line 97.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:98: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/1f4a2.pdf' not found on input line 98.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:99: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/1f5ef.pdf' not found on input line 99.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:100: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/1f620.pdf' not found on input line 100.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:101: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/1f627.pdf' not found on input line 101.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:102: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/1f41c.pdf' not found on input line 102.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:103: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/1f34e.pdf' not found on input line 103.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:104: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/2652.pdf' not found on input line 104.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:105: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/2648.pdf' not found on input line 105.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:106: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/25c0.pdf' not found on input line 106.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:107: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/23ec.pdf' not found on input line 107.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:108: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/23eb.pdf' not found on input line 108.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:109: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/2b07.pdf' not found on input line 109.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:110: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/1f53d.pdf' not found on input line 110.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:111: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/25b6.pdf' not found on input line 111.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:112: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/2935.pdf' not found on input line 112.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:113: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/2934.pdf' not found on input line 113.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:114: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/2b05.pdf' not found on input line 114.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:115: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/2199.pdf' not found on input line 115.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:116: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/2198.pdf' not found on input line 116.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:117: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/27a1.pdf' not found on input line 117.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:118: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/21aa.pdf' not found on input line 118.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:119: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/2b06.pdf' not found on input line 119.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:120: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/2195.pdf' not found on input line 120.
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\beamer\emojione\emojione.sty:121: LaTeX Warning: File `./pdf/1f53c.pdf' not found on input line 121.
```

Comment: Did you also copy the folder PDF, which contains all the symbols as individual `.pdf` files?

Comment: I have tried that. It's not working

Comment: Could you provide an example document (MWE) that you tried? Which errors do you get? Which output, if any?

Comment: I have added in the question. Please have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `emojione` package is about 2 years old. Meanwhile the LaTeX3 stuff had at least one update. And the `emojione` package wasn't changed accordingly.

You need to change `emojione.sty`, line 57, from

```
\bool_if:nTF { \xetex_if_engine_p: || \luatex_if_engine_p:}
```

to

```
\bool_if:nTF { \sys_if_engine_xetex_p: || \sys_if_engine_pdftex_p:}
```

Then the errors reported for `emojione.sty` should be gone.

The package calls `\includegraphics[...]{.pfd/...}` to insert the picture. This means, the folder `pdf` is expected to be in the same folder as your `.tex` file.

There are two possibilities to solve this. You can copy the `pdf` folder to
the folder of your `.tex` file or you change line 54 of `emojione.sty` from

```
              {\c_emojione_folder / #1.\c_emojione_extension}%
```

to

```
              {#1.\c_emojione_extension}%
```

With this the pictures will be found, if the `pdf` folder in the same folder as the `emojione.sty` file.